# Navigation Drawer on all activities - my app does not show the map as an activity from drawer

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to create an android app that uses Google Maps and tried to add it into an Navigation Drawer on all activities app but the map doesn't show. I am trying to develop an app that uses the drawer to navigate between activities, one of them being created using Google Maps. The map activity starts, a toast message with "Map is ready" is present, and when I click on the grey screen(where the map should appear), I get the toast message telling me the longitude and latitude, which means the map is working somehow, on the back of the layout. I believe the situation is caused by some miss-written layout text, but I couldn't manage to find the cause so I will add the xml's files here, maybe someone could spot a mistake that I didn't see. I also tried the put the fragment containing the map last on the xml, as I read that this may be the cause of not showing the map, but still no change. In the MapsActivity.java i also have a `linearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, which if I change to `VISIBLE`, it appears on the screen, over the inexistent map. Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried a simplified method to just show the map, without any other functions but the situation is the same, the map won't load. The manifest has all the permissions needed and also dependencies. I used those files
:
FirstActivity.java

```
package com.example.navigationdrawer2;

import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync( this);
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        set(navMenuTitles, navMenuIcons);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

Activity_first.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <fragment
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/map"
             tools:context="com.example.navigationdrawer2.SecondActivity"
             class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#e5e5e5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As the FirstActivity extends BaseActivity, i will add that .java too.

BaseActivity.java:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private Menu menuObject;
private CharSequence mTitle;
Toolbar toolbar;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer);
}

public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    if (navMenuIcons == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                    navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }
    }
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.menu, 
            R.string.app_name 
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        displayView(position);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

void setupDrawerToggle(){
    mDrawerToggle = new androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, null, false);
mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0); 
}
```

in onCreate of YourActivity don't call setContentView instead do above snippet:

```
FrameLayout convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_rows, parent, false);
```

you must be change "parent"="framLayout" you need to add framLayout in drawer activity and give reference.

Comment: I have tried this solution but I get this error: `UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, int) is not supported in AdapterView`

Comment: convertView  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_rows, parent, false);  you must be change "parent"="framLayout" you need to add framLayout in drawer activity and give reference.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Activity` you have to use `setContentView` instead of `Inflater`. Try like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ....
}
```

Comment: I have changed the `Inflater` with `setContentView` and added the `mapFragment` part, but the app hasn't change it's behaviour. The screen is still grey and I still get the toasts messages of "Map is ready" and the latitude and longitude when I click.

Comment: Add `onMapReady` and also where you set lat and long

Comment: I have `OnMapReady` setted already. From there I get the toasts messages that i said about before. Should I add the full MapsActivity.java code?

Comment: Have you add valid `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` in `Manifest`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have double checked it.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the full MapsActivity.java